# Need Reporting System for Restful API Data

Tags: reporting, saas

Is there a SaaS tool which will let me interface to a XML based Restful API and do advanced reporting on it?  We have a basic report generating system in our application, but need a more advanced solution for some of our customers...

Answer (score 2):

you can find information on GoodData's REST APIs, integration with Talend, Java sample code, and other tips and tricks on our support forum - this is a good place to start: http://support.gooddata.com/forums/46715/entries/77166

Feel free to email support@gooddata.com if you want some help.

Thanks
-Sam [sam@gooddata.com]

Answer (score 1):

What about something like [Good Data](http://www.gooddata.com) or [Zoho reports](http://reports.zoho.com)?

Are you wanting to have their reports inside your SaaS app? Or is it ok for them to provide the dashboarding?

Comment: One of the online Business Intelligence apps (GoodData & YouCalc) may end up being how we go, but they don't seem to be able to handle a basic Restfull api too well.  YouCalc does support this, but it's a pain to get running.

Seems that there should be an easier/simpler solution out there for basic reporting, but I haven't been able to find it yet.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understand what you want to achieve. I assume that you have a REST API based application and you want to analyze it's traffic. The pure Apache log analysis doesn't work as you need more API level analysis (analyzing your application's events).

I think that we something similar. Our application produces an audit log and error log that we load into GoodData and analyze it there.

Let me know if you are interested in more details.